# How to toggle caps lock key on virtual keyboard

Tags: android

Is there a way to get a reference to the soft key board currently on screen, and toggle one of the keys? This is what I mean:

```
KeyBoard keyBoard = getSoftKeyboard();
bool toggleState = toggleState(CAPS_KEY);
if(toggleState == true) toggleKeyState(CAPS_KEY);
```

I basically want to toggle the key that makes the initial letter of the input string in an EditText to false.

Thanks

Comment: ALTERNATE solution: you could use a TextWatcher on your EditText and lower the case on each key press, even if the user has the caps on.

Answer (score 1):

in XML you can make first letter capital auto keyboard configuration enable using

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

on your EditText.

Programmatically in your activity onCreate

```
EditText editor = new EditText(this); 
editor.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```